# Laravel MongoDB 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: php, laravel, database, mongodb, connection

I've I have a problem with my MongoDB connection. I am trying to connect my MongoDB database to my shared webhost, when I am trying to access any routes that are using MongoDB stuff returns:

```
503
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily busy, try again later!
```

I checked my error logs and I can't find anything wrong or anything that is realted to my problem.

```
2021-10-14 16:47:44.066927 [INFO] [66574] [T0] [209.124.68.228:35630#APVH_ ] File not found [/home/rorpro/ /503.shtml] 
2021-10-14 16:47:43.114577 [INFO] [66572] [T0] [209.124.68.228:35542-1#APVH_ ] File not found [/home/rorpro/ /503.shtml] 
2021-10-14 16:47:40.093929 [INFO] [66572] [T0] [209.124.68.228:35300-6#APVH_ ] File not found [/home/rorpro/ /503.shtml]
```

On my localhost works perfect but this error occurs only on my shared host. I tried to connect my mongodb with package **mongodb/mongodb** and works but with **jenssegers/mongodb** doesn't.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!